# Problem in selection Dataset in R commander

Tags: r, dataset, runtime-error, selection, r-commander

Trying to select active Dataset in R commander it doesn't do this command in R console giving an error: Error in get(dsname, envir = .GlobalEnv) : invalid first argument
Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] bad window path name ".20"

Although it shows the view of the right dataset other functions like recoding don't work.
How could I solve it? That is the first time I came across with it.

Comment: OS? The fact that the error involves Tcl suggests to me that perhaps it's on a Mac.

Comment: no, that is on IBM windows. Seems I clarified - that is bug

Comment: If you think you found a bug, then you should first make sure it is repeatable on an up-to-date installation of your OS _and_ of R _and_ of the package and then follow the recommended reporting method. What I have observed is that suspected bugs in Rcmdr get the most prompt attention on the R help mailing list. An alternate strategy would be to execute: `maintainer("Rcmdr")` and send a full problem description via email (typically the code used or clear description of the actions as well as the  output of `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Thanks, we discussed that with maintainer.